# How to replicate all resources/stack to another aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to clone my aws account(prod) to another account(test) with all resources and configuration I have set up on prod. Is there any best practice to replicate the aws account to another?

Answer (score 2):

This is **not possible**.

Nor is there an easy way to list all resources in an AWS account.

Each AWS Service (eg EC2, S3, Lambda) have their own API calls to list resources and describe configurations. **There is no *universal* way to request this information.**

**Best Practice is to only create resources using AWS CloudFormation templates**, thereby having full documentation of resources created and the ability to deploy similar infrastructure in other AWS accounts or regions.

Some third-party services (eg https://www.hava.io/) can extract configuration information and **automatically create AWS CloudFormation templates**. However, these templates only record the configuration of AWS resources -- they do not replicate the content of storage on disks, Amazon S3 or databases.

Comment: Thanks John! Then seems this is an arduous task..AWS should introduce a new service 'Cloud Replica' to do the same to ease developer life.

Comment: If I will go with CloudFromation templates, will it create exact my resources in another account?  I meant will it create my same Lambda functions, APIs in Gateway and all ? or it will create only configuration related to the resources i.e. roles, permissions, etc. ?

Comment: AWS CloudFormation will create the resources defined in the CloudFormation template you provide. You can include Lambda functions, API Gateway definitions and most services. Think of it like an automated version of the Management Console.